# What's the point of JAVA_HOME environment variable

Tags: java, windows, path

What is the point of setting JAVA_HOME environmental variable when the only thing you have to set is the Path variable to call java from the command line, which is the primary purpose, right ?

Comment: There wouldn't be much point if that was all it was used for.  Other programs use it, though the `java` on the path is usually enough.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What are other uses for those paths and variables other than to be able to invoke an executable through command line from any directory ?

Comment: Some programs use JAVA_HOME is their startup script e.g. IntelliJ does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAVA_HOME is just a convention, usually used by Java EE app servers like Tomcat and build tools such as Gradle to find where Java lives.

You could also use JAVA_HOME to set the PATH variable, something like this..

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

So that you dont have to meddle with PATH variable every time, if you have to switch between two JDKs or two JREs of different versions

Answer (score 2):

Some application takes JAVA_HOME to execute/configure themselves instead of using the java executable in the PATH: tomcat, [maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html), weblogic, eclipse, etc...

So it's a good idea to have this variable properly set.

Comment: but that's what my question is about: if those applications can see java in the PATH what's the point ? If JAVA_HOME and PATH are pointing to the same executable?

Comment: @ShadyProgrammer What if they don't? I believe I have at least two Java installations on my laptop, what if I want to switch which one is used without messing with $PATH?

Comment: Okay I've got you :) Thank you

Comment: That's. If you have some Java versions, JAVA_HOME is an easy way to switch from one to another.

Answer (score 1):

IMO this is a unix thing where the OS's files are saved. Windows is totally different. But since Java is installed into Program files in Windows it doesn't make sense either.